# Uniform convergence Check

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Question is to check :

[image]

I guess i am through with $(c)$ i.e., i see it as an infinite geometric series and say that :

$$x^2+\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}+\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}+\dots = \frac{x^2}{1-\frac{1}{1+x^2}}=1+x^2$$

So, this infinite series actually converges and is actually finite in given interval..

So, can i just say this converges "Uniformly"? I guess i can say.. but i am not sure..

I tried to somehow make second series interms of just exponential popwers but then i ruined it. (as you can see in previous form of this post)

I have no idea about first question...

I would be thankful if some one can help me with this Question.

Thank You

EDIT : Thanks to Mr.Ayman for suggesting Weierstrass Test , I tried some thing in that way :

$$|a_n \cos nt +b_n \sin nt|\leq |a_n||\cos nt| +|b_n| |\sin nt|\leq |a_n|+|b_n|$$

I only know $\sum _{n} |a_n| < \infty$ and $\sum _{n} |b_n| < \infty$ and i guess this would imply $$\sum _{n} |a_n|+|b_n|<\infty$$ which is sufficient to deal with case $(a)..$ but i am not so sure how to write this explicitly..

please help me in this case..

Thank You

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Weierstrass M-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test)? Also, posting text is much better than images because it's searchable.

Comment: I have read about weirstrass M- test.. but i am not sure how to use it in this case.. could not found suitable bounds... :O

Comment: Please check your transform from Cos[x] to exponentials.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici : Oh my bad... I did not realize that ... Thank you...

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik. You welcome.

Comment: Regarding c), take another look at $x = 0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer  :( may be i should not consider $\frac{x^2}{1-\frac{1}{1+x^2}}$... but i am confused why should not i do this.... :(

Comment: That's absolutely fine for $x \neq 0$. But for $x = 0$, you get an indeterminate form $\frac00$. What does the series converge to for $x = 0$, and what does that tell you about the possibility of uniform convergence?

Comment: yes.. so this would imply that it is not uniformly convergent... :O

Comment: NBHM analysis question. I can not remember the year.

Comment: it is NBHM 2006 question....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weirstrass M-Test is saying If $|f_n|\le  M_n\forall n$ and $\sum M_n$ is convergent Then $\sum f_n$ is uniformly convergent. Note That Converse is not true.

We will apply this result to solve 
$a.$

where $f_n(t)=a_n\sin nt+b_n\cos nt$, clearly $|f_n|\le a_n+b_n=M_n$ as $\sum (a_n+b_n)$ is given convergent so $\sum f_n=a_n\sin nt+b_n\cos nt$ is uniformly convergent

for $b$ you have done! and it is not UC

$c$ use the fact that if the sequence of continuous function converges uniformly to a function then the limit is also continuos

so only $a$ is true!

Comment: tumi ato jano!!!

Comment: @Samprity  amar onek kichhu tumi jano, ta ami janina

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik lets chat on facebook ;)